# How to fit all cells in horizontal listview: JavaFx

Tags: listview, user-interface, javafx, cell, scenebuilder

I have horizontal listview. And i also have put it into anchor pane and set constraints. When window resize listview width also change.
So i want to make all cells in same size and fit all cells to listview width.
Then i resize the window, width of cell auto change.

[image]

```
    public class MainStageController {

    @FXML
    private ListView<String> listView;
    ObservableList<String> items;

    public void initialize() {  
       items = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Dashboard","Drivers","Cars","Travels","Summary","Settings");
       listView.getItems().addAll(items);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `ListView` is the correct control in this case? Maybe use an `HBox` and set the `HGrow` property of the children to `ALWAYS`?

Comment: How do i do that